# problema basico con clase partial c#

Tags: c#

tengo un problema, me pinta un error al querer llamar a un atributo de otra clase, entiendo que como ambos cuentan con la clase partial deberia de funcionar, muestro imagenes.

Aqui mi clase partial donde muestro los atributos que tiene la partial clase Haberes_ate (imagen 1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego creo otra clase partial "haberes" y defino lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde estara mi error, ayuda porfa.

Comment: Las clases parciales deben tener el mismo nombre

Comment: haces referencia a que deben de tener el mismo nombre ambas clases?

aqui una imagen: https://ibb.co/nRkL7jj

Comment: Claro, ambas deben llamarse `Haberes` (ojo las CLASES...los archivos pueden tener cualquier nombre)

Comment: Ejemplo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRJjI.png

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado.